# publishing WCF webservice in network

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

i have a C# WCF project, i have added a websevice inside,
now i wish to publish it, so that another computer on the same network could access the service using the address http:/IPAddress:Port/webservice
how is it done?
thank you very much

Comment: oops i ment http:/IPAddress/webservice

Comment: Is the wcf service in a separate project?

Comment: You could host the WCF in IIS, if you go to the project properties you will find the option to host WCF in IIS, or you can write you own hosting application

Comment: the wcf contains the web service